# Safari 13+ box-shadow only shows up when content is not empty

Tags: css, safari, zurb-foundation

I am having a problem with a `box-shadow` attribute not showing up when the `content` attribute is empty ("") and viewed in Safari. I can reproduce it with Safari 13.1.3 and have reports from users on iOS 14.

Here is the CSS (it is the Foundation 5 responsive burger menu icon).

```
.top-bar .toggle-topbar.menu-icon a span:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: -8px;
    top: 50%;
    right: 21.666px;
    right: 1.3541666667rem;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #fff, 0 7px 0 1px #fff, 0 14px 0 1px #fff;
    width: 16px;
}
```

As soon as I enter something in the `content` attribute, the box-shadow will show. So I could of course add a point in the content and make it disappear with a `color: transparent`.

Is there a real solution to it? It is Working in current Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: Maybe height: 0 is killing your boxShadow?

Comment: Why is it working in Chrome and Firefox? It could work, but when I add a `height: 1px`the first bar of the burger icon has a different color.

Comment: @Lazar NikoIic I tried it: adding height to the CSS scales the box-shadow up. So it is just another hack and not the solution I am looking for.

Comment: Why not put the box shadow on the element rather than the :after selector?

Comment: @k123 There is no element. It took me some time to understand how the Icon works, but the `span` is empty, and the `:after` is generating the icon. The box-shadow is the icon.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fix that worked for me.

The bug seems to be manifesting itself in Chrome / Safari on MacOS (~10.15) and iOS (~14.3) for some projects that we were using Foundation 5 on.

Adding some height seemed to work for our projects

```
.tab-bar .menu-icon span {
   height: 2px;
   box-shadow: 0 10px 0 0px #fff,0 16px 0 0px  #fff,0 22px 0 0px #fff;  
}
```

You can check out a comparison in this [Codepen](https://codepen.io/prembo/pen/WNGmMxB).  Blue row is standard Foundation and red row has the fix.